# Firebase conversions on Google ads?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, google-ads-api

I don't really know if im in the correct forum, but please if not, point me in the right direction.

I have a little problem: I have setted up a campaing for downloads of the App from a client (A corporation) this campaing is setted on the objective of the first_open(Android) on firebase. I've talked with my associated account executive and he tells me we should also have another campaing with a first_open (iOS) objective.
Here is where the problem starts. The google executive tells me we should have an event called first_open (iOS) which should be a separated event from first_open (Android), but I can't find this. It's not listed as an event on firebase nor google analytics web + app, I've tryed creating this event on my own but can't seem to get it working.

If I go into firebase conversions or events, I can only see one first_open event, that I can use a filter on, and see Android/iOS independently, but I can't seem to export it in separate to Google Ads conversions. There are some events called something like this, but they show 0 conversions.

If I can use the filter on firebase to see iOS first opens, how come I cant seem to see this conversions in Ads??

Also, how come I can extract this "Conversion events" from firebase, through google ads, but I'm not able to see them on firebase nor analytics?

Thank you!

Comment: did you find how to fix this?

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue. In my Firebase settings, my iOS App was missing the app id and team id.  After filling in that data, I was able to setup a iOS conversations in Google Ads.

Answer (score 2):

To add to Mark Currie's answer -

As soon as I entered App Id and Team Id in Firebase, iOS conversions started showing in Google Ads.

For finding team id, as of today, you have to look at Apple Developer Account => Identifiers => App ID prefix

Answer (score 1):

We had exactly the same issue. I have done 2 things that solve the problem.

1. Supplied the missing App ID in Firebase
2. Setup `adSupport.framework` in the app